# localhost:3000が開けません

Tags: javascript

https://localhost:3000/1/pg185.html が開けません。ｈｐの試作をクラウドを使ってアップロードしたいと思い、試みているのですが、開けません。webアドレスを取得したい？思うのですが。

Answer (score 2):

自分のコンピュータに web server がインストールされていて、正しく起動できていて、ポート 3000 で待ち受けていて、その web server の公開ドキュメントディレクトリに `1/pg185.html` を配置すれば開けるはずです。時と場合によってはセキュリティソフト（ウイルス対策ソフト）のファイアウォール設定を変更してポート 3000 を開く必要があるでしょう。